# Does the Android Network Provider exist on Android Studio Emulators?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, genymotion, locationmanager

I am trying to reverse engineer an app that uses the [Android LocationManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager). It is attempting to request location updates via the `.requestLocationUpdates` method. However, I am receiving an error that the network provider doesn't exist:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider doesn't exist: network
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2075)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
    at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:1151)
    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:1019)
    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:558)
```

This error logged after clicking a button in the app and then it crashed. At the time of executing this action, I was using Genymotion Desktop Emulator running a Samsung Galaxy S10 on Android 11.0 API and x86 architecture. After some [research](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9945), it seems like the issue is due to the fact that Genymotion does not have a network provider enabled. After even more research, it seems [emulators can't use the network provider period](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14490948/7011067).

I'm not an Android expert and all of the links aren't exactly the same as my case, so I'm trying to see if there is still a work around/if the outcomes of these links fully apply to me.

Since my issue seems to be Genymotion related, I have decided to try and use Android Studio's emulator instead. I have created a virtual device via the Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD). It is a Nexus 5 API 30 using Android 11.0 (Google Play) on x86 architecture. It is my understanding that there are [three location providers in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6775456/9613109) and the one that I need is the `network` provider.

**My main question is:** Do Android Studio Emulators have the network provider enabled?

If not, is it even possible for an emulator to have it enabled or should I consider purchasing a real android phone for this case?

You may be asking why I don't just try to click the same button and see if the error replicates. Well, I simply can't right now. The reason is quite complex, but in short, the button only shows up occasionally for me to press. I don't know when it will be available again, so in the meantime I'm trying to prepare my setup and gain a better understanding of android's location manager.